# How to analyse a discrete dynamical system on the unit circle?

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

I have this problem but I don’t know how solve it:

> Describe the dynamic of $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ given by:
>
> $$f(\theta)= \theta+\frac{\pi}{n}+a\sin(n\theta),$$
>
> where $0<a<\frac{1}{n}$.

I know that $S^1$ is the unit circle in the plane. But I don’t understand how solve it. I have plotted $f(\theta)$ in $ℝ^2$ and  does not cross the identity. Does this mean that $f$ does not have fixed points? How  do I represent this in the circle?

Comment: What is $sen(n\theta)$?  $\sin(n \theta)$?

Comment: Also: What is $n$?

Comment: Yes, in my country we use "sen" sorry, and I do not know, I think that "n" is a natural number.

Comment: *I think that "n" is a natural number* – Okay, so it’s not the designated variable for the time?

Comment: This problem is in a Devaney's book about dynamical systems but he doesn't specify nothing about n in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you four hints:

- Always simulate the dynamics for some initial conditions and parameters first to get an idea of what is going on.
- You may as well be looking at the dynamics of $g: [0,2π]→[0,2π]$ with $g(θ) = f(θ) \bmod 2π$.
- Start with the case $a=0$.
- If $f(θ)$ doesn’t have any fixed points, is there some $m∈ℕ$ for which $f^m(θ)$ does?